# How to share Preferences in a Xamarin.Forms project between an iOS and iOS extensions?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-extensions

I'm trying to get a string (UserID) using `Preferences.Get`  (Xamarin.Essentials) on a `PushNotification.Extension` project, but as the `Preferences.Set` happens in the Xamarin iOS project, I'm always getting an empty string in the extensions project.

Is there a way to share this preference between the iOS project and the iOS.extension?

```
public string UserID
{
    get
    {
        return Preferences.Get(nameof(UserID), UserIDDefault);
    }
    set
    {
        Preferences.Set(nameof(UserID), value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) , please follow the steps to enable data-sharinig .

1. Enable `App Groups` Capabilities , [refer to App Group Capabilities in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/capabilities/app-groups-capabilities).
2. [Add the app to the App Group](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19) .
3. Use `NSUserDefaults` and init it with the name of the extension bundle identifier.

```
//Save 
var defaults = new NSUserDefaults(@"com.example.domain.MyShareExtension");
defaults.SetString("value","Mykey");
defaults.Synchronize();
```

```
//Get
var defaults = new NSUserDefaults(@"com.example.domain.MyShareExtension");
var value = defaults.ValueForKey("Mykey");
```

Answer (score 0):

"NSUserDefaults(string)" does not work for me.
In the Xamarin iOS documentation this constructor is marked as deprecated! see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsuserdefaults?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

But when I use "NSUserDefaults(String, NSUserDefaultsType)" it runs perfect.